# How can I determine if the user has an existing B2C session before proceeding with the user journey?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to execute a custom policy for a user, but only if the user has already logged in through the signup_signin policy. Can I use the B2C session state? How can I store a claim in the user's B2C session in during signup_signin, and then access that claim in a different policy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSO [session management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso).

"To add claims in the session, use the  element of the technical profile. When the provider is used to repopulate the session, the persisted claims are added to the claims bag".

Just be consistent across the session provider you use.

Comment: i am trying to achieve a similar flow so asking it here. i have an invitation only sign up custom policy. i want to add a predicate in my sign up policy to check if a user is logged in the same browser. ideally would like to stop the sign up flow if a user is already logged in. is there any inbuilt claim i could use?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of.